# React Native адаптивная вёрстка

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

Начал изучать react native и столкнулся с проблемой адаптивной вёрстки. Можно ли писать адаптивные стили, которые будут подстраиваться под разные экраны? Есть nativewind, но он не везде используется и поддержка кода усложняется на мой взгляд. И так как RN кроссплатформенный, то будут ли эти стили корректно отрабатывать и на iOS или каким-то образом нужно будет писать несколько стилей под разные устройства? Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли сделать вёрстку сразу на несколько устройств и платформ.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: В react native нет медиа запросов. Это ведь не браузер.

Comment: У тебя в метках стоит css. Я не знаю что там как в react native и почему нет браузера (в чём я сильно сомневаюсь , но если используется css, то адаптив делается мелдиазапросами.

Comment: Обычно такого рода проблемы решали с помощью react native normalize, и в принципе он  у нас всегда обязательно использовался на всех проектах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `react-native` насколько я знаю нет привычных нам медиа запросов, но когда у меня был опыт с ним, я использовал хук [useWindowDimensions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions) из `react-native` для получения ширины экрана.